# Is eternal inflation compatible with inflation starting at $10^{-34}$ second after the big bang?

Tags: big-bang, cosmological-inflation

[Eternal inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation) is taking place in an eternally inflating 4-d spacetime.

It is "commonly" assumed that inflation (whatever its cause may be) took off (big bang) at about $10^{-34}$ second.

Then how can both kinds be compatible, as eternal inflation starts at time zero? Or is the last a wrong assumption?

Comment: Why the downvote? Non-mainstream?

Comment: My understanding is that eternal inflation, being a hypothetical extension to standard inflationary models, still relies on the idea that inflation began due to a phase transition in the very early Universe. Could you provide a source for the claim that eternal inflation 'starts at time zero'?

Comment: Right now I can't but I'll look for it.

Comment: In the cited article it is said that inflation **ends** at $10^{-34}$ second, instead of **taking off** at that time.